# In a CDI extension, what's the easiest way to tell whether an injection point will be satisfied?

Tags: cdi

I am writing a CDI extension.

What is the easiest way to find out if a given injection point will be satisfied during bean deployment, and to remove it if it won't be satisfied?

`ProcessInjectionPoint`-time is too early, because bean discovery hasn't completed yet, so you can't tell, of any given `InjectionPoint`, whether a bean exists to satisfy it.

`ProcessInjectionTarget`-time also seems to be the wrong place, because although all injection points have already been read there isn't a way to now remove one.

I need an event that lets me remove an injection point from an injection target if I can determine that the injection point won't be satisfied.

(Background: I am messing about with programmatically translating Guice's `com.google.inject.Inject` annotation (which features an `optional` attribute).)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to do that, not this way at least. Your issue sounds very similar to what was discussed in [CDI-45 issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/CDI-45), it might be worth describing this use case there.

For your case, one thing that comes to me is usage of `@Inject Instance<MyBeanClass>` instead of classical injection. This allows you to detect (in runtime) whether you have any (or more than one) bean which satisfy the IP. I don't know anything about `com.google.inject.Inject` and its `optional` feature, but CDI `Instance` seems pretty close to that.

**EDIT:** A colleague of mine came with one brilliant idea which might help you. You will still use an extension and you will observe the `AfterBeanDiscovery` phase. Now you will want to verify if there is unsatisfied resolution **manually** using `BeanManager`. For that purpose you will likely go with `BM.resolve(BM.getBean())`. Now if you find that some of your optional IPs is not satisfied, you will want to call `AfterBeanDiscovery.addBean(myWrapperBean)`. Where `myWrapperBean` is your impl (wrapper) of the `javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Bean` interface. This wrapper will be a 'dummy producer' basically returning `null`.

And that should do it, although it will not work for *custom beans*, e.g. beans added via `AfterBeanDiscovery`, but I guess that is OK for you.

Comment: Indeed it does, but unfortunately the code I'm working with (that I don't control) used `com.google.inject.Inject(optional = true)` instead.  Hmm. Basically I am looking to effectively intercept the injection point at container validation time, and if it is found to be bad, just set the relevant field/parameter to `null` instead.  I don't think that requires a context I don't have—surely CDI's typesafe resolution algorithm has all the context it needs here? What I'm missing is a mutator at the right point in the lifecycle. I probably need to introduce a generated producer method instead.

Comment: Oh I see, misunderstood you. In that case the first part of my answer doesn't make much sense, ignore that. Yes, the type resolution mechanism does verify the conditions at app initialization and indeed has enough info for that. Yet still I know of no 'mutator' mechanism which could help you here. Your issue sounds exactly like what was discussed at [CDI-45 issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/CDI-45) - would be worth to add a comment there explaining this use case. Or hit us on Weld forums/issue tracker so we can discuss this further. Meanwhile I'll update answer here.